# Typescript: Is it possible to use a property of a type as a type?

Tags: typescript

I would like to infer types from the current object and on its implementation. The following FruitPicker has a property of fruitKey, which will determine the return value of the Function. Is it possible to connect those.

```js
type Lookup = {
  banana: Banana;
  apple: Apple;
  peach: Peach;
};

type FruitPicker = {
  (
    deliveredFruits // TypeBasedOn FruitPicker.availableFruits
  ) => Lookup[this.fruitKey] // type based on FruitPicker.fruitKey
  fruitKey: keyof Lookup;
  availableFruits: (keyof Lookup)[];
}

// implementation of FruitPicker:
const fruitPicker: FruitPicker = (
  deliveredFruits // should be dependant on the type of available Fruits
) => {
  // working with the fruits
  // has to return type Banana because its fruitKey is 'banana'
}
fruitPicker.fruitKey = 'banana'
fruitPicker.availableFruits = ['apple', 'peach'];
```

i was successful connecting them like this:

```js
type FruitPicker<Key extends keyof Lookup, AvailableFruits extends keyof Lookup> = {
  (availableFruits: Pick<Lookup, AvailableFruits>) => Lookup[Key];
  fruitKey: Key,
  availableFruits: AvailableFruits[];
}
```

But i always have to pass the generic arguments, even if it could be read from the implementation.